# Get current RabbitMQ Channel in Spring Batch SkipListener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-batch, channel

I have a RabbitMQ triggered Spring Batch application.

I need to **nack** the message on exception. However, Spring Batch doesn't throw Exceptions outside the run method. Thus, I need to **nack** the message in the **SkipListener**. I have managed to get the message tag as a **JobParameter**, but I am not able to send **Channel** as a **JobParameter**, since it is not **Serializable**.

Is there any way how to pass the **Channel** to the batch process or any other way of error handling ?

This is an example of what I have right now.

MessageConsumer.java

```java
import com.project.common.dto.DataImportStartDto;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.AmqpHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MessageConsumer {

    private final DataImportService dataImportService;

    public MessageConsumer(DataImportService dataImportService) {
        this.dataImportService = dataImportService;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "etl_queue", concurrency = "1", ackMode = "MANUAL")
    public void receiveDataImportMessage(DataImportStartDto dataImportStartDto, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws Exception {
        dataImportService.startImport(dataImportStartDto, tag);
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
    }
```

DataImportService .java

```java
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

public class DataImportServiceImpl implements DataImportService {

private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
private final Job dataImportJob;

@Service
public DataImportServiceImpl(JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("dataImport") Job dataImportJob) {
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    this.dataImportJob= dataImportJob;
}

@Override
public void startImport(DataImportStartDto dto, long tag) {
    jobLauncher.run(dataImportJob, buildJobParameters(dto, tag));
    }
}

private JobParameters buildJobParameters(DataImportStartDto dto, long tag) {
    return new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("unique", String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID())) // needed if there are jobs with the same parameters running in parallel
        .addLong("tag", tag)
        .toJobParameters();
}
```

BatchExceptionHandler.java

```java
import org.springframework.batch.core.SkipListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@StepScope
@Component
public class BatchExceptionHandler implements SkipListener<IntervalDataWrapper<String>, IntervalDataWrapper<String>> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['tag']}")
    private long tag; // this value is here on onSkipInRead execution


    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
        // channel.basicNack(tag, false, true); // this is what I need to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(IntervalDataWrapper<String> item, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(IntervalDataWrapper<String> item, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

**IntervalDataWrapper** is my custom data wrapper with batch configuration.

Comment: What does "current RabbitMQ channel" mean? You know upfront which channel your job is reading from or writing to correct? Why not declaring that channel as a bean an inject it in your skip listener?

Comment: Channel is being injected to the method call annotated with @RabbitListener, it is not a Bean. I need to access this channel outside the method call in the SpringBatch.

Comment: I am not, there is no such bean. I guess it is generated per request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should not be doing that `nack` in the skip listener. Those calls are not at the same level of abstraction IMO. What I understand from your implementation is that you want to `nack` when there is an error on read. Your current setup is now:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "etl_queue", concurrency = "1", ackMode = "MANUAL")
public void receiveDataImportMessage(DataImportStartDto dataImportStartDto, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws Exception {

   // run a job
   dataImportService.startImport(dataImportStartDto, tag); // send nack = true from within the job

   // when the job is finished, send nack = false
   channel.basicAck(tag, false);
}
```

So as you can see, one acknowledgment is sent from within the job and the other one is sent outside the job. What I would do is if there is a skippable exception, I would set the exit status of the job to something like `FINISHED_WITH_SKIPS` (or even fail it if needed) and then check the status of the job to know which type of acknowledgement should be sent to the channel:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "etl_queue", concurrency = "1", ackMode = "MANUAL")
    public void receiveDataImportMessage(DataImportStartDto dataImportStartDto, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws Exception {

   JobExecution jobExecution = dataImportService.startImport(dataImportStartDto, tag);
   if (jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("FINISHED_WITH_SKIPS") {
      channel.basicNack(tag, false, true);
   } else {
      channel.basicAck(tag, false);
   };
        
}
```

This approach does not require the channel to be injected in the skip listener. Moreover, this approach keeps the batch processing logic separate from the messaging logic which is easier to test, deploy and think about.

Comment: Oh right, jobExecution also gives me getAllFailureExceptions, I didn't know that. I can list all of the exceptions. Thank you very much.